# Profiling doesn't work on WTK emulator

Tags: java, java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

It used to work, so I know what's meant to happen. You run the emulator and once you're done with it and close it a profiling window pops up and gives you a summary of time spent in different methods.

It seems to have stopped working for me. I run my app in the emulator, close it and get this on the console instead:

```
Warning: Could not start new emulator process:
  java.lang.NullPointerException
Result: 1
```

Can anyone perhaps explain why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I sometimes receive this error if my midlet uses too much CPU - lots of repaints and processing. 
Also, try giving more memory to JVM with -Xmx512m, or -Xmx1024m params (I don't sure if it could help)